# PL/SQL regex validation how to escape from '

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I'm working on a fullName validation function, examples that can go are :

John Deep

JohnDeep

John-Deep

I want to use this regex:

```
^\p{L}+[\p{L}\p{Pd}\p{Zs}']*\p{L}+$|^\p{L}+$
```

My validation function is :

```
 create or replace FUNCTION is_valid_fullName (str IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
        bln BOOLEAN;
    begin       
     if regexp_like(str, '^\p{L}+[\p{L}\p{Pd}\p{Zs}']*\p{L}+$|^\p{L}+$') then

            return 1;
      else 
        return 0;
     end if;
     end;
```

However I have a problem with syntax.

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "]" when ...

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To input a single quote in a string double it.

Your pattern is a bit redundant, you may get rid of the alternation using an optional group:

```
^\p{L}+([\p{L}\p{Pd}\p{Zs}']*\p{L}+)?$
       ^                           ^^
```

**However**, you can't use Unicode property classes in an Oracle regex. What you may do is use *POSIX* `[:alpha:]` character class instead of the `\p{L}` to match any Unicode letter and spell out the `\p{Pd}` (`[\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010\u2011\u2012\u2013\u2014\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]`) and `\p{Zs}` (`[\u0020\u3000\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2008\u2009\u200A\u205F\u00A0\u2007\u202F]`) Unicode property classes. You may also consider using the POSIX `[:space:]` / `[:blank:]` character classes instead of `\p{Zs}` because `\p{Zs}` matches all horizontal whitespace *BUT* a tab char.

A converted pattern will look like

```
'^[[:alpha:]]+([-[:alpha:]' || unistr('\058A') || unistr('\05BE') || unistr('\1400') || unistr('\1806') || unistr('\2010') || unistr('\2011') || unistr('\2012') || unistr('\2013') || unistr('\2014') || unistr('\2015') || unistr('\2E17') || unistr('\2E1A') || unistr('\2E3A') || unistr('\2E3B') || unistr('\2E40') || unistr('\301C') || unistr('\3030') || unistr('\30A0') || unistr('\FE31') || unistr('\FE32') || unistr('\FE58') || unistr('\FE63') || unistr('\FF0D') || unistr('\0009') || unistr('\3000') || unistr('\1680') || unistr('\2000') || unistr('\2001') || unistr('\2002') || unistr('\2003') || unistr('\2004') || unistr('\2005') || unistr('\2006') || unistr('\2008') || unistr('\2009') || unistr('\200A') || unistr('\205F') || unistr('\00A0') || unistr('\2007') || unistr('\202F') || ' '']*[[:alpha:]]+)?$'
```

Or, if you use `[:blank:]`:

```
'^[[:alpha:]]+([-[:alpha:][:blank:]' || unistr('\058A') || unistr('\05BE') || unistr('\1400') || unistr('\1806') || unistr('\2010') || unistr('\2011') || unistr('\2012') || unistr('\2013') || unistr('\2014') || unistr('\2015') || unistr('\2E17') || unistr('\2E1A') || unistr('\2E3A') || unistr('\2E3B') || unistr('\2E40') || unistr('\301C') || unistr('\3030') || unistr('\30A0') || unistr('\FE31') || unistr('\FE32') || unistr('\FE58') || unistr('\FE63') || unistr('\FF0D') || ' '']*[[:alpha:]]+)?$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://rextester.com/XPINY41692) (`1` means there was a match).

Answer (score -1):

```
regexp_like(str, '^\p{L}+[\p{L}\p{Pd}\p{Zs}']*\p{L}+$|^\p{L}+$')
```

I think it's the second single quote just between p{Zs} and ]*\p

Edit:
When doing regex I like online too like,  : [regexTester](https://www.regextester.com) or [regex101](https://regex101.com/)
There is example for some useful regex too.

Comment: Oracle regex does not support Unicode property classes.

Answer (score -1):

If the examples you gave are the only things that should match then use:
  `regexp_like(str, '^\p{L}+[\p{L}\p{Pd}\p{Zs}]*\p{L}+$|^\p{L}+$')` 

But if you want the regex to match "Jhon o' Deep" then you have to somehow escape that `'` character.